# Stack pop giving segment fault

Tags: c++, stack

The stack which I'm using is not empty and I did a check for that still getting segment fault.
Let s="aaabbaaccd"

```
string removePair(string s){
  stack<char>st;
  st.push(s[0]);                  //Doing this,So that first pop without insert doesn't cause error.
  string output="";
  for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
    if(st.top()!=s[i])
        st.push(s[i]);
    else if(st.top()==s[i] && st.empty()==false){
        st.pop();               //Gives Segment fault.
    }
  }
  while(st.empty()==false){
    output+=st.top();
    st.pop();
  }
  reverse(output.begin(),output.end());
  return output;
}
```

[Check Full Code Here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/X0E6qAXxlO)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
if(st.top()!=s[i])
    st.push(s[i]);
else if(st.top()==s[i] && st.empty()==false){
```

You check if the stack is empty, but you do that too late. At the point you call `st.empty()` you already called `st.top()` twice. You need to check if there is an element **before** you try to access it. I am not sure about the logic of the code, but I suppose in the first condition you want to `push` into an empty stack, otherwise check if `s[i]` equals `top`:

```
if(st.empty() || st.top()!=s[i])
    st.push(s[i]);
else if(!st.empty() && st.top()==s[i]){
```

Note that both `||` and `&&` are short-circuiting. Hence in `A || B` if `A == true` then `B` will not be evaluated. Similar in `C && D`, if `C == false` then `D` will not be evaluated.